# Variable in list name

Tags: python

I have this code :

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE date=?",(date,))
for row in cur:
    list_foo.append(row[2])
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM bar WHERE date=?",(date,))
for row in cur:
    list_bar.append(row[2])
```

It works fine, but I’d like to automize this. I have made a list of the tables in my sqlite database, and I’d like something like this :

```
table_list = ['foo','bar']
for t in table_list:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM "+t+" WHERE date=?",(date,))
    for row in cur:
        # and here I’d like to append to the list which name depends of t (list_foo, then list_bar, etc.)
```

But I don’t know how to do that. Any idea ?

Comment: You an use Dict to storge "list_name" -> []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *dictionary* to collect your data. Don't try to set new local names for each list.

You could use string templating too, and a list comprehension to turn your result rows into lists:

```
data = {}

for t in table_list:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE date=?".format(t), (date,))
    data[t] = [row[2] for row in cur]
```

One caveat: only do this with a pre-defined list of table names; don't ever interpolate untrusted input like that without hefty escaping to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: If you ever have to do this with non-predefined teble names, reject all which contain a backtick and enclose the table names with a backtick. Then all what can happen is an invalid table name, but not an attack. So, `for t in table_list:` `if '\`' in t: raise Whatever` `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM \`{}\` WHERE date=?".format(t), (date,))`